# Are questions about the use of cpanel web interface on-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I asked a question about cpanel and ssh keys generated in puttygen. I've deleted it now, but high-rep users can see it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712535/how-can-i-import-a-pair-of-pub-ppk-to-cpanel

The [cpanel tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpanel) details the use of the web interface. These questions appear to be are about configuration and using a site that is SASS. Since it's about using software as opposed to programming, are questions about its use on topic to SO?

Would they be better posted to superuser, serverfault or another SE site?

Comment: Related question about ssh keys http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220734/are-questions-about-the-use-of-ssh-keys-on-topic