# Are questions about the use of ssh keys on topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I asked a question about cpanel and ssh keys generated in puttygen. I've deleted it now, but high-rep users can see it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712535/how-can-i-import-a-pair-of-pub-ppk-to-cpanel

Since I'm using the ssh keys to configure cpanel and authenticate my machine, this question is about the use of software (e.g. puttygen, or cpanel's key generation) rather than programming. Are questions about ssh keys on topic for SO?

Would they be better posted to superuser, serverfault or another SE site?

Comment: Related question about cpanel http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220733/are-questions-about-the-use-of-cpanel-web-interface-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question would be more appropriate on [Super User](http://superuser.com). StackOverflow is designed for programming question and not software configuration.

See the [F.A.Q](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for more information:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: So if post a Linux command script that is not working and I need help on it on Stack Overflow, it's better to put it on Super user?

Comment: @puretppc If it's a script, that means there's programming work underneath. It can be on StackOverflow so.